# Something like a Go To?

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently making a simple stupid UI(User Interface) for some vbs scripts I've made. I just added a part where it asks the User's name in the beginning. My problem is every time I use this "Back" Option to go to a previous "tab" It redoes the asking your name. I've looked for many different ways to get it to work but I can't. I can't find away for the Loop/exit thing to work. I tried making the name script separate so it runs it at the beginning and when you go back it goes to the main script. But that would mean I wouldn't know their names on the second script as it wouldn't have the variable values. Here's the script!.

```
Dim Input
Dim Input1
Dim Input2
Dim Input3
Dim InputName
InputName = Inputbox("Please Enter Your Name", "Name")
Input = Inputbox("Weclome " & InputName & "" & vbNewLine & "Choose One Of The Options!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Information" & vbNewLine & "Cool" & vbNewLine & "Hacks" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Solus")
If Input = "Information" Then
    Input1 = Inputbox("Here's The Information!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Info" & vbNewLine & "Speech" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Information")
    If Input1 = "Info" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Info.txt"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input1 = "Speech" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Speech.vbs"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input1 = "Back" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input1 = "Quit" Then
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    End If
ElseIf Input = "Cool" Then
    Input2 = Inputbox("Here's Some Scripts!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Abracadabra" & vbNewLine & "Calculator" & vbNewLine & "Matrix" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Cool")
    If Input2 = "Abracadabra" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Abracadabra.vbs"
    ElseIf Input2 = "Calculator" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Calculator.vbs"
    ElseIf Input2 = "Matrix" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Matrix.bat"
    ElseIf Input2 = "Back" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input2 = "Quit" Then
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    End If
ElseIf Input = "Hacks" Then
    Input3 = Inputbox("Here's Some Hacks!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Failure" & vbNewLine & "Haxs" & vbNewLine & "Rekt" & vbNewLine & "Spam" & vbNewLine & "TheOnly" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Hacks")
    If Input3 = "Failure" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Failure.vbs"
        Set Wsh Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf  Input3 = "Hacks" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Haxs.vbs"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input3 = "Rekt" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Rekt.vbs"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input3 = "Back" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input3 = "Spam" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Spam.bat"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input3 = "TheOnly" Then
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    ElseIf Input3 = "Quit" Then
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    End If
ElseIf Input = "Quit" Then
    Wscript.Quit
Else
    msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
End If
```

How I made the "Back" option work is by rerunning the program so it would start at the beginning again. With adding the "Back" to the main script it will be the first thing to run and will happen each time you go back. Which I can't have. And if I decided to make the name part separate so it wouldn't be ran the main script would loose the name variable and couldn't use it and it would be useless. I'm new here so sorry if I made some mistakes.
Thanks in advance!
BTH

Comment: This code could really use some white space, indention, and comments. It's a very hard to understand wall of code.

Comment: @JNevill, I took care of indentation already. It is being peer reviewed.

Comment: I notice you are creating a new `WScript.Shell` object for each `If` statement. If you have to do it everytime, it is not part of the condition so you could move it to the top. You only need one `Shell`object to run your code. Secondly, if you need to have that much condition evaluated, consider `Select Case` instead. Last but not least, give some research on `Do..While...Loop` to take care of your coding. Unfortunately I'm not able to give an actual answer right now because I'm stuck with other things in here, but if you haven't received any reply later on, I will give it a try.

Comment: You may want to look into [HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (HTA) for programming user interfaces with VBScript.

Comment: Thanks, sorry new here

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Goto` statement available, but it's generally considered bad practice to use it since it turns your code into spaghetti. Alternatively, a loop would be a good approach here. You'll keep looping after you collect the name until the person enters "Quit" in the outer dialog:

```
Dim Input
Dim Input1
Dim Input2
Dim Input3
Dim InputName

InputName = Inputbox("Please Enter Your Name", "Name")
Do While Input <> "Quit"
    Input = Inputbox("Weclome " & InputName & "" & vbNewLine & "Choose One Of The Options!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Information" & vbNewLine & "Cool" & vbNewLine & "Hacks" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Solus")

    If Input = "Information" Then

        Input1 = Inputbox("Here's The Information!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Info" & vbNewLine & "Speech" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Information")

        If Input1 = "Info" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Info.txt"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input1 = "Speech" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Speech.vbs"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input1 = "Back" Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Input1 = "Quit" Then
            Wscript.Quit
        Else
            msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        End If

    ElseIf Input = "Cool" Then

        Input2 = Inputbox("Here's Some Scripts!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Abracadabra" & vbNewLine & "Calculator" & vbNewLine & "Matrix" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Cool")

        If Input2 = "Abracadabra" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Abracadabra.vbs"
        ElseIf Input2 = "Calculator" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Calculator.vbs"
        ElseIf Input2 = "Matrix" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Matrix.bat"
        ElseIf Input1 = "Back" Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Input2 = "Quit" Then
            Wscript.Quit
        Else
            msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        End If

    ElseIf Input = "Hacks" Then

        Input3 = Inputbox("Here's Some Hacks!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Failure" & vbNewLine & "Haxs" & vbNewLine & "Rekt" & vbNewLine & "Spam" & vbNewLine & "TheOnly" & vbNewLine & "Back" & vbNewLine & "Quit", "Hacks")

        If Input3 = "Failure" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Failure.vbs"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf  Input3 = "Hacks" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Haxs.vbs"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "Rekt" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Rekt.vbs"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input1 = "Back" Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Input3 = "Spam" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Spam.bat"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "TheOnly" Then
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "Quit" Then
            Wscript.Quit
        Else
            msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
            Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        End If
    Elseif Input = "Quit" Then
        'do nothing. While loop will exit
    Else
        msgbox("Please Enter One Of The Options Next Time!")
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Another good idea would be to break the code up into *functions*. Using more constants wouldn't be a crazy idea either to reduce duplication of all those paths. GoTo *can* turn your code into spaghetti if you wield it like a blunt weapon, but it's not as bad as the rap it gets. Really, a loop is just syntactic sugar for a GoTo!

Comment: Couple things. Mainly thanks for your help!!! I tried running the script and it had some bugs. When I ran it and tried using "Back" It read it as an unknown entry and stuff. The Quit didn't work and in the end I ended up with 3 looped scripts. My main thing is to get the "Back" Function to skip the Name function. Sorry about the mess. I'll fix it.

Comment: I thank you for all your help. I know it's my fault. I really need to learn more about subs and functions!

Comment: I've ran this code as is and had no problem with it. The only issue is if you don't enter one of the options and it pops itself back open. Not sure what you are doing there. Is it to force them to enter a new name? I would almost tend towards the "Else" acting the same as the "Back" to reprompt in the outer dialog.

Comment: You guys mentioned there is a `GoTo`, but the only `GoTo` I know in `VBSscript` is `On Error GoTo 0`. Nothing like `GoTo ErrorHandler`, as existing in `VBA`, for instance. Am I wrong? Is there any other `GoTo` that can be used in `VBScript`?

Comment: My apologies. I believe you are right that goto is only available for error handling. Subroutines might be the best bet to sort of emulate Goto type stuff, outside of doing a loop like above.

Comment: Sorry about that JNevill. It won't work for you since you don't have the directories and stuff. If you want I can send it to you as I made it. The part I posted above is only a part. I have it set up like an installer.

Comment: That's fair. It works fine for me if I select any of the options in the first selection and then "back" in any of the next selections. Which is what the question was about. Now, if one of the scripts is calling happens to kick back to this main script, then it's going to prompt for name again. That's why it would be like 100x better to redesign and have all of your scripts as subroutines inside one vbs file.

Comment: Is there anyway I can show you how I have it set up? I have one big script I can send to you that when ran would work. It's kind of hard to explain other wise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this in case anyone is looking for a working version.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell, Input, Input1, Input2, Input3, inputName, optNum
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'=========================================================================
'Function to check that the input is valid
'=========================================================================
FUNCTION InvalidCheck(ByVal optNum)
    IF IsEmpty(Input) THEN
        wscript.Quit
    ELSEIF Input = "" THEN
        wshShell.Popup Space(2) & "Please select an option or click Cancel to quit.",4,Space(40) & "Retry or Quit",vbExclamation
    ELSEIF NOT IsNumeric(Input) THEN
        wshShell.Popup "Only numbers are valid.",4,SPACE(15) & "Non numeric entry",vbExclamation
        IF Input = Input1 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input1"
            Input1 = ""
        ELSEIF Input = Input2 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input2"
            Input2 = ""
        ELSEIF Input = Input3 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input3"
            Input3 = ""
        ELSE
            Input = ""
        END IF
    ELSEIF Input > optNum THEN
        wshShell.Popup "Only 1 - " & optNum & " are valid entries.",4,SPACE(25) & "Invalid entry >",vbExclamation
        IF Input = Input1 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input1"
            Input1 = ""
        ELSEIF Input = Input2 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input2"
            Input2 = ""
        ELSEIF Input = Input3 THEN
'           wscript.echo "Input is set to input3"
            Input3 = ""
        ELSE
            Input = ""
        END IF
    END IF
END FUNCTION
'=========================================================================
'Get user's name
'=========================================================================
DO
    InputName = Inputbox(vbNewLine & vbNewLine & SPACE(25) & "Please Enter Your Name.",SPACE(40) & "Name Entry")
    IF IsEmpty(InputName) THEN
        wscript.Quit
    ELSEIF InputName = "" THEN
        wshShell.Popup Space(2) & "Please enter your name or click Cancel to quit.",4,Space(40) & "Retry or Quit",vbInformation
    END IF
LOOP WHILE InputName = ""
'=========================================================================
'Menu Navigation
'=========================================================================
DO
    Input = Inputbox(SPACE(40) & "Welcome " & InputName & "!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Choose One Of The Options:" &_
    vbNewLine & vbCR & "(1) Information" & vbCR & vbCR & "(2) Cool" & vbCR & vbCR & "(3) Hacks" & vbCR & vbCR & "Click Cancel to quit",SPACE(45) & "Solus")
    optNum = "3"
    InvalidCheck optNum 
    IF Input = "0" THEN
        wshShell.Popup "Only 1 - " & optNum & " are valid entries.",4,SPACE(25) & "Invalid entry",vbExclamation
        Input = ""
    END IF
'=========================================================================
'   "Information" Menu Navigation
'=========================================================================
    IF Input = "1" Then
        DO
        Input1 = Inputbox(vbCR & "(1) Info" & vbCR & vbCR & "(2) Speech" & vbCR & vbCR &_
        "(0) Back" & vbCR & vbCR & "Click Cancel to quit",SPACE(35) & "Information Menu")
        optNum = "2"
        Input = Input1
        inValidCheck(optNum)
        IF Input1 = "1" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Info.txt"
        ElseIf Input1 = "2" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Information\Speech.vbs"
        ElseIf Input1 = "0" Then
            Input = ""
            optNum = ""
        End If
        LOOP WHILE Input1 = ""
'=========================================================================
'   "Cool" Menu Navigation
'=========================================================================
    ElseIf Input = "2" Then
        DO
        Input2 = Inputbox(vbCR & "(1) Abracadabra" & vbCR & vbCR & "(2) Calculator" & vbCR & vbCR &_
        "(3) Matrix" & vbCR & vbCR & "(0) Back"& vbCR & vbCR & "Click Cancel to quit",SPACE(45) & "Cool")
        optNum = "3"
        Input = Input2
        inValidCheck(optNum)
        If Input2 = "1" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Abracadabra.vbs"
        ElseIf Input2 = "2" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Calculator.vbs"
        ElseIf Input2 = "3" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Cool\Matrix.bat"
        ElseIf Input2 = "0" Then
            Input = ""
            optNum = ""
        End If
        LOOP WHILE Input2 = ""
'=========================================================================
'   "Hacks" Menu Navigation
'=========================================================================
    ElseIf Input = "3" Then
        DO
        Input3 = Inputbox(vbCR & "(1) Failure" & vbCR & vbCR & "(2) Haxs" & vbCR & vbCR & "(3) Rekt" & vbCR & vbCR &_
        "(4) Spam" & vbCR & vbCR & "(5) TheOnly" & vbCR & vbCR & "(0) Back"& vbCR & vbCR & "Click Cancel to quit",SPACE(45) & "Hacks")
        optNum = "5"
        Input = Input3
        inValidCheck(optNum)
        If Input3 = "1" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Failure.vbs"
        ElseIf  Input3 = "2" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Haxs.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "3" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Rekt.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "4" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Hacks\Spam.bat"
        ElseIf Input3 = "5" Then
            WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Solus\Solus.vbs"
        ElseIf Input3 = "0" Then
            Input = ""
            optNum = ""
        End If
        LOOP WHILE Input3 = ""
    End If
Loop While Input = ""

'=========================================================================
'Cleanup
'=========================================================================
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**